# how to work with a ToggleButton android

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

I have the following ToggleButton in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="ToggleButton"
            android:textOff="Inactive"
            android:textOn="Active" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/check_note"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="25px" />
        ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my class that extends a listview I would like to programatically set the togglebutton on active/inactive based on some criterias. I would like to specify that I do not what the user to be able to click on the togglebutton and set it on active or inactive. How to do that? Need some help. Appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to make the button not clickable, just disable the toggle button:

```
mToggleButton.setEbabled(false);
```

or set it not to be clickable:

```
mToggleButton.setClickable(false);
```

and for programatically change the button state, use:

```
mToggleButton.setActivated(true); 
mToggleButton.setActivated(false);
```

Comment: thx! i will try it. is there a way to disable the button in the xml layout?

Comment: yes, you can do it on the xml file also - just use the attribute -  android:clickable="false" or android:enabled="false"

Comment: there is no setActivated in my list for the togglebutton

Answer (score 1):

The answer with  `ToggleButton.setActivated` didn't work for me.  I used the following to get it to work:

```
 ToggleButton.setChecked(false);
```

Hope this helps anyone else with the same issues.